# How to keep windowTranslucentStatus, yet able to "push up" and "resize" launched dialog fragment

Tags: android

Currently, I'm using the following theme in my activity

```
<style name="Theme.JStock.Toolbar.Transparent.Light" parent="@style/Theme.JStock.Base.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I use `windowTranslucentStatus`, because I want the status bar to "follow" the color of my toolbar. The color of my toolbar changed dynamically.

[image]

**However, this also create an undesired side effect.**

When I launch a dialog fragment from the activity, the dialog cannot be "pushed up" and "resized"

[image]

If I remove `windowTranslucentStatus`, and change my activity theme to

```
<style name="Theme.JStock.Toolbar.Transparent.Light" parent="@style/Theme.JStock.Base.Light">
    <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**The dialog will "pushed up" and "resized" as expected.**

[image]

However, I don't want to remove `windowTranslucentStatus` either. I want the status bar to have same color as toolbar dynamic color. As you can see after removing `windowTranslucentStatus`, the status bar becomes black color.

May I know, how is it possible I can keep `windowTranslucentStatus`, yet able to "push up" and "resize" launched dialog fragment?

Comment: and if you set translucent status to the dialog theme?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Thanks. It works. Would you like to add it as answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: yes, I add an answer to help other people :)

Comment: @CheokYanCheng can you please give an example? I am using MaterialAlertDialogBuilder and DialogFragment in my code. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like i said in comments you can use this inside theme of **dialog**:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: can you please give an example? I am using MaterialAlertDialogBuilder and DialogFragment in my code. How am I supposed to do this?